# How to get "Last contribution amount" and "Last contribution date" into report?

Tags: custom-fields, civireport, reports, custom-reports, sql

I'm needing a way to add 2 columns to contribution summary report, 1 for displaying "last contribution date" and 1 for "last contribution amount" in a CiviReport. Is there an easy way using the UI to do this? If not, is there a way to write a plain SQL query that shows up as a report?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way we have approached this in the past is to install/enable the [Summary Fields extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields), and set that up so it calculates the Last Date and Last amount, which are then available as custom fields you can add to any report.

Comment: As @pete has mentioned, yes use summary fields. Referencing a CiviCRM TV session we did only a couple of weeks ago on the subject. https://youtu.be/vJ7QZxLgogQ